# Variable will not be set when using SET /P inside IF statement

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7, windows-7-x64

I've written a simple batch file to install a program under Windows 7. There's a maddening bug I'm running into with `set /p VAR=PROMPT`:

## Input discarded bug

Here's a simple test case:

```
@echo off
setlocal

if exist "%USERPROFILE%\Documents" (
    set /p CONFIRM="Previous version is installed! Continue? (Y/n) "
    echo {%CONFIRM%}
)

if exist "%USERPROFILE%\Documents" (
    set /p CONFIRM="Previous version is installed! Continue? (Y/n) "
    echo {%CONFIRM%}
)
```

I run it:

```
Previous version is installed! Continue? (Y/n) n
{}
Previous version is installed! Continue? (Y/n) n
{n}
```

**Notice that when the first `set /p` runs, it doesn't actually save my input!**

## Prompt mangling bug (related?)

I suspect, but am not sure, if this is related to a more obvious bug in `set /p`, wherein it truncates the prompt at the first `)` if inside the parentheses defining the `if` block:

```
@echo off

if exist "%USERPROFILE%\Documents" (
    set /p CONFIRM=Previous version is installed! Continue? (Y/n)
    echo {%CONFIRM%}
)
```

At least this version captures my input, although it mangles the prompt:

```
Previous version is installed! Continue? (Y/nn
{n}
```

## Workarounds?

Any ideas? Or is `set /p` just so buggy that I can't use it?

## EDIT: Conclusions

Thanks to the links and tips from @npocmaka, I think I have a better idea what's going on: "parse time" vs. "run time" isn't the same inside a `()`-delimited block as outside. Hence this example:

```
@echo off

(
    set /p CONFIRM=^?
    echo {%CONFIRM%}
)

(
    set /p CONFIRM=^?
    echo {%CONFIRM%}
)

echo {%CONFIRM%}
```

When run, it's obvious that there's a "delay" in the variables getting the expected values inside the blocks:

```
?foo
{}
?bar
{foo}
{bar}
```

**Although delayed expansion works, I still believe this behavior is inconsistent with every description I've read of how `set /p` is supposed to work, though that's par for the course for batch files. It appears that variables set by `set /p` magically escape from parse-time expansion *except* when they appear inside blocks.**

I believe the "prompt mangling" version only works (sorta) because it inadvertently closes the block early, and the batch file processor doesn't complain about the second mismatched `)`.

Comment: delayed expansion....

Comment: npocmaka, adding `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` doesn't make a difference. Although I suspect this is a parser bug, it's not obviously related to variable expansion in any way.

Comment: when delayed expansion is used variables should be enclosed with `!` instead of `%` .At least the if they are within brackets.

Comment: Thanks, using `!CONFIRM!` does the trick. I still don't understand the root cause though, because without the enclosing `if` statement, it works fine (meaning that `%CONFIRM%` gets evaluated at run time, not parse time).

Comment: Here's exhaustive overview of how cmd parses scripts: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133/388389  . More fore delayed expansion - http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html  and http://www.robvanderwoude.com/variableexpansion.php

Comment: I edited the question title to reflect the problem so future readers may find it more easily.  People ask questions that require delayed expansion every day - it's the most FAQ lately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

if exist "%USERPROFILE%\Documents" (
    set /p CONFIRM="Previous version is installed! Continue? ^(Y/n^) "
    echo {!CONFIRM!}
)

if exist "%USERPROFILE%\Documents" (
    set /p CONFIRM="Previous version is installed! Continue? ^(Y/n^) "
    echo {!CONFIRM!}
)
Endlocal
```

Does this work?